# Отслеживание удалённых данных во всех вкладках браузера

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Рассмотрим ситуацию на примере сайта ВКонтакте. На стене Вашей страницы имеются ваши личные записи. Если открыть две одинаковые вкладки и в первой вкладке удалить запись на стене, то эта запись автоматически удаляется и во второй вкладке. Каким образом можно реализовать подобный приём? Меня интересует не программный код, а последовательность операций и теоретическая модель. Я могу организовать long poll для проверки данных на сервере. Но есть некоторые неудобные моменты, при проверке этих данных на стороне сервера. Что я имею ввиду? Если в первой вкладке вы удаляете запись, в таблице БД она сразу же помечается флагом 0. Наш long poll во второй вкладке должен увидеть этот флаг и вывести результат. Да. Он увидит этот флаг. Но при следующей попытке обращения к данным, он снова увидит этот флаг в позиции 0 и опять выдаст нам результат, хотя мы в этом уже не нуждаемся.

Долго над этим раздумывая, я реализовал один вариант. Но он несовершенен. Порядок операций таков:

1. Открываем long poll во второй неактивной вкладке.
2. Получаем массив идентификаторов активных(flags=1) записей на стене, учитывая пагинацию.
3. Через цикл (каждые 2 секунды) подставляем этот массив идентификаторов в запрос и проверяем их на состояние flags=0.
4. Если какие-то записи из набора идентификаторов были удалены, мы возвращаем их идентификаторы клиенту, а тот в свою очередь удаляет их со своей страницы.
5. Открываем новый long poll и снова ждём, когда у нас будут удалены ещё какие-нибудь записи.

Вариант работает. При удалении записи в одной вкладке, эта же запись удаляется и в других вкладках и также во вкладках других браузеров. Но минус данного подхода в том, что запрашиваемый массив идентификаторов может быть очень большим, ведь он прямо пропорционален количеству записей на странице. Если у меня на стене будет 1000 записей, то он будет запрашивать идентификаторы всех этих записей и искать среди них, удалённые записи. Каждые 2 секунды проверять 1000 записей, это довольно накладно.

Может у кого-то есть другие идеи?

Comment: Проверять каждые 2 секунды изменения будет проще, если при совершении изменений заносить их в отдельный массив, а при проверке брать только оттуда (N последних или после даты)

Comment: К тому же, может получится отказаться от проверки в цикле в пользу событий, например, получение страницей фокуса или пролистывание. В момент переключения на вторую вкладку или пролистывания к старым записям страница шлет запрос для проверки изменений и приводит его в актуальное стостояние

Comment: @Mi Ke Bu, правильно ли я понимаю? В момент удаления записи, мы сразу заносим в отдельный массив дату удаления. Во второй вкладке, мы сверяем текущее время с датой удаления. Если скажем удаление произошло не более 2 секунд назад, то значит отправляем эту запись клиенту, для того, чтобы он убрал эту запись со стены.

Answer (score 1):

Все несколько абстрактней.

В приложении существует некоторый менеджер очередей. Туда сваливаются все события - пост Х удален, стена Х обновилась, к посту Х пришел комментарий. К этому же менеджеру подсасываются клиентские приложения, подписываясь на те или иные потоки событий, которые этот менеджер начинает им раздавать, и с каждым ajax-запросом сервер просто отдает то, что накопилось с предыдущего, либо живьем форвардит сообщения по веб-сокету. Благодаря тому, что все это висит в оперативке (возможно, лишь скидывая слишком длинные списки на диск), никаких проверок делать не нужно, и все работает довольно быстро.

В целом можно посмотреть pub/sub и его реализации на каком-нибудь redis.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не совсем правильный подход в реализации, точнее говоря он неправильный совсем. Давайте попробуем взять именно ваш подход и реализовать именно Long Poll и забудем пока про Веб сокеты.

В чем ошибка вашего варианта? Ваш Long Poll ищет изменения в существующем списке объектов и пытается на эти изменения отреагировать. Это решение очень сложное и  требует большого кол-ва ресурсов. Поэтому мы его сразу отметаем. Наш сервис не должен сам искать изменения. Ему эти изменения кто-то должен сообщать. Должно наступать какое-то событие. Писать события в реляционную базу нельзя (либо делать запись во временную таблицу в памяти). Лучше использовать какой нибудь MemCache.

Следующая проблема с которой мы столкнемся в будущем, это то, что требуется какая-то система подписок на интересующие нас события. Нам же не нужно чтобы LongPoll ждал все события сервера. Поэтому в LongPoll нам нужно создать какие-то виртуальный комнаты на которые пользователь будет подписываться, а также можно добавить систему прав.

Итогом всех этих рассуждений является то, что использовать необходимо более современные решения и взглянуть на WebSocket более внимательно и пристально, а longpoll оставить только для старых браузеров.

Comment: Вебсокеты хороши, однако требуют накладных расходов на поддержание соединения и их количество имеет лимит. Это решение может упереться в потолок по ресурсам

Comment: @MiKeBu, long polling куда быстрее выжрет все ресурсы сервера.

Comment: @Etki, согласен, но я не агитирую за long-pooling) есть и тривиальные запросы

Comment: @MiKeBu, окей, они быстрее сожрут лимиты по трафику.

Comment: @Etki, Какие ресурсы сервера, выжирает long poll? Ведь это всего лишь цикл с проверкой условия, с ожиданием в 2 секунды после каждой итерации. Например ВКонтакте полным ходом использует long poll.

Comment: @StasHappy большое количество подключений + (в случае PHP) пбольшие накладные расходы на поддержание каждого (замеры не делал, но если каждый процесс сжирает - предположительно - 7-8 мб, то это быстрый путь в истощение). Вк может использовать, что хочет, и затыкать свои проблемы деньгами.

Comment: @Etki, Хорошо. Сразу возникает вопрос. При использовании Long poll мы делаем одно подключение на каждые 30 секунд. Без использования long poll, мы уже откроем в общей сложности 15 подключений в течение 30 секунд, по одному запросу каждые 2 секунды. Одно меньше чем 15.  А следовательно на одно подключение должно быть меньше ресурсов чем на 15 подключений. Как Вам такая ситуация?

Comment: @StasHappy вы, кажется, забываете о количестве клиентов. При 200 клиентов и 200 мс на ответ общие времязатраты составят 6000 машиносекунд, при лонг поллинге в худшей ситуации это возрастет до условных 60000 машиносекунд. Ну и попрошу не забывать, что если клиент отключился, то оперативка на него уже не тратится, поэтому спрашивать про то, насколько больше расходуется на 15 последовательных подключений - это, мягко говоря, некорректно.

Comment: Короче, в теории это можно построить без особых напрягов для машины. Но у меня есть серьезные сомнения, что FPM внутри построен так, чтобы это позволять.

Comment: @MiKeBu уже не первый раз вижу на SO упоминание каких-то лимитов у вебсокетов, и мне всё ещё непонятно — какие там лимиты-то?

Comment: @Etki, я не отношу себя к знатокам этой темы. Но вопросы люблю задавать. Нет вопросов, нет ответов. Нет ответов, нет знаний. У меня вопрос по поводу оперативки. Отражается ли на оперативке работающий цикл, с проверкой условия? Притом что мы ничего не выводим в буфер. Мы просто проверяем в цикле два значения. Неужели простая проверка условия, сжигает много оперативки?

Comment: Я провёл эксперимент. Запустил long poll. Он работал 30 секунд. В качестве ответа от сервера, вывел количество байт, которое было затрачено во время работы этого скрипта. Показало 45880 bytes. То есть один 30 секундный long poll жрёт 44,8 килобайт.

Comment: @StasHappy Разрешите вмешаться в ваш разговор и добавить свои 5 копеек. Представьте себе отдельно стоящий WebSocket сервер как отдельный программный продукт. На одно соединение с ним он тратит ровно столько ресурсов сколько нужно чтобы открыть один сокет в системе. Если вы с этим согласны, то легко сможете понять, что для того чтобы исполнить один PHP скрипт нужно существенно больше ресурсов на каждое отдельное соединение. Да, от выбора веб сервера и метода обработки PHP результаты будут разными, но  всегда больше WebSocket сервера написанного как отдельное приложение.

Comment: @StasHappy если вы следили через всякие memory_get_usage, то не забудьте приплюсовать сюда сам интерпретатор и накладные расходы.

Comment: @Etki, можно узнать, что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите о "накладных расходах"? И ещё один вопрос. `memory_get_usage()` разве не указывает на то, сколько памяти было выделено скрипту интерпретатором?

Comment: @StasHappy вот именно что скрипту, сам интерпретатор, установка соединения и прочее тоже жрут. С другой стороны, в линуксе есть shared objects, поэтому я не знаю, насколько накладно вызывать второй интерпретатор и как это устроено в FPM.

Comment: @Etki, что ж, придётся изучать webSockets и всё переделывать в своём проекте.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос. Если long poll такой неэффективный, зачем его тогда вообще придумали? Зачем он нужен?

Comment: @StasHappy Long poll придумали гораздо раньше, чем браузеры начали поддерживать WebSocket на достаточно приемлемом уровне. Даже сейчас отказываться от Long Poll или Comet полностью не получается из-за старых браузеров или ограниченных прокси блокирующих работу вебсокета.

Comment: @Ruslan, если его придумали гораздо раньше, то значит и компьютеры были слабже для тех времён и браузеры не столь совершенны. Но тем не менее люди всё же использовали long poll. И ещё. Сайт Вконтакте, прекрассно мог отказаться от long poll в пользу webSockets. Но у них диалоги, сообщения, приложения и прочее, работают именно на нём. Если webSockets так хорош, то почему они это не сделали.

Comment: @StasHappy Здесь  не чат, поэтому общение в комментариях не приветствуется. Есть ответ от инженера Фейсбука почему они не используют вебсокет. Общий его смысл такой "Зачем мы будем что-то менять, если то что сделано в общем работает без сбоев". Когда делались оба этих проекта Вебсокеты не поддерживались браузерами в должной степени. Даже сейчас вебсокеты не поддерживаются некоторыми версиями браузеров, а также имеют проблемы прохождения прокси. Но есть проекты использующие только WebSocket. Например [Agar.io](http://agar.io/) и работать на longpoll он бы не смог совсем. Выбор всегда за вами.

Comment: @andreymal, кратко: 1) сокеты поддерживают соединение открытым, на это идут ресурсы процессора, оперативки, сети; 2) в отличии от однократных запросов ресурсы не освобождаются после отправки ответа, лишь при закрытии соединения; 3) ресурсы конечны, отсюда и лимиты. В Apache вроде даже прописано максимальное количество открытых соединений (~150).

Comment: @MiKeBu Long Poll это тоже поддержание соединения открытым.

Comment: @MiKeBu внезапно, ровно те же самые проблемы и у long poll =) И для вебсокетов надо юзать nginx, а для высокнагруженных сайтов типа SO (тут вебсокеты, да) и ВК несколько серверов - и ни одной из перечисленных проблем не будет.

Comment: Ребята. На первое время оставлю long poll. Немного переделал так, как предложил `Mi Ke Bu` в своём первом комментарии, говоря о проверке даты удалённой записи. Всё в принципе работает прекрасно. Данные со страницы удаляются.